# Search for the next day format in a database

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on fetching the data from the database. I want to search for the next day format for the `program_start_date`, example: the `program_start_date` format show `20171107200000` so I want to search for the next day format which it is `20171108200000`.

Here is the code:

```
channels_list = self.channel[self.channels_Index:min(len(self.channel), self.channels_Index + 7)]


if len(self.programs_button) > 0:

    #CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    conn = database.connect(self.profilePath + 'source.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for channels in channels_list:
        cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs where channel=? LIMIT 1', [channels])
        programs = cur.fetchall()

        for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
            program_start_date = str(row[2])
            start_time = time.strptime(program_start_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
            start_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(start_time))

            print program_start_date
```

Here is the `program_start_date` data:

```
20171107200000
20171107210000
20171107220000
20171107223000
20171107224500
20171107232500
20171108000500
20171108001000
20171108060000
20171108091500
20171108100000
20171108110000
20171108114500
20171108121500
20171108130000
20171108133000
20171108134500
20171108141500
20171108150000
20171108154500
20171108163000
20171108171500
20171108180000
20171108183000
20171108190000
20171108200000
20171108210000
20171108220000
20171108223000
20171108224500
20171108231500
20171108234500
20171109004500
20171109005000
20171109060000
20171109091500
20171109100000
20171109110000
20171109114500
20171109121500
20171109130000
20171109133000
20171109134500
20171109141500
20171109150000
20171109154500
20171109163000
20171109171500
20171109180000
20171109183000
20171109190000
20171109193000
20171109200000
20171109210000
20171109220000
20171109223000
20171109224500
20171109234500
20171110004500
20171110005000
20171110060000
20171110091500
20171110100000
20171110110000
20171110114500
20171110121500
20171110130000
20171110133000
20171110134500
20171110141500
20171110150000
20171110154500
20171110163000
20171110171500
20171110180000
20171110183000
20171110190000
20171110193000
20171110200000
20171110203000
20171110210000
20171110213000
```

And here is the `start_time` data:

```
2017-11-07 20:00:00
2017-11-07 21:00:00
2017-11-07 22:00:00
2017-11-07 22:30:00
2017-11-07 22:45:00
2017-11-07 23:25:00
2017-11-08 00:05:00
2017-11-08 00:10:00
2017-11-08 06:00:00
2017-11-08 09:15:00
2017-11-08 10:00:00
2017-11-08 11:00:00
2017-11-08 11:45:00
2017-11-08 12:15:00
2017-11-08 13:00:00
2017-11-08 13:30:00
2017-11-08 13:45:00
2017-11-08 14:15:00
2017-11-08 15:00:00
2017-11-08 15:45:00
2017-11-08 16:30:00
2017-11-08 17:15:00
2017-11-08 18:00:00
2017-11-08 18:30:00
2017-11-08 19:00:00
2017-11-08 20:00:00
2017-11-08 21:00:00
2017-11-08 22:00:00
2017-11-08 22:30:00
2017-11-08 22:45:00
2017-11-08 23:15:00
2017-11-08 23:45:00
2017-11-09 00:45:00
2017-11-09 00:50:00
2017-11-09 06:00:00
2017-11-09 09:15:00
2017-11-09 10:00:00
2017-11-09 11:00:00
2017-11-09 11:45:00
2017-11-09 12:15:00
2017-11-09 13:00:00
2017-11-09 13:30:00
2017-11-09 13:45:00
2017-11-09 14:15:00
2017-11-09 15:00:00
2017-11-09 15:45:00
2017-11-09 16:30:00
2017-11-09 17:15:00
2017-11-09 18:00:00
2017-11-09 18:30:00
2017-11-09 19:00:00
2017-11-09 19:30:00
2017-11-09 20:00:00
2017-11-09 21:00:00
2017-11-09 22:00:00
2017-11-09 22:30:00
2017-11-09 22:45:00
2017-11-09 23:45:00
2017-11-10 00:45:00
2017-11-10 00:50:00
2017-11-10 06:00:00
2017-11-10 09:15:00
2017-11-10 10:00:00
2017-11-10 11:00:00
2017-11-10 11:45:00
2017-11-10 12:15:00
2017-11-10 13:00:00
2017-11-10 13:30:00
2017-11-10 13:45:00
2017-11-10 14:15:00
2017-11-10 15:00:00
2017-11-10 15:45:00
2017-11-10 16:30:00
2017-11-10 17:15:00
2017-11-10 18:00:00
2017-11-10 18:30:00
2017-11-10 19:00:00
2017-11-10 19:30:00
2017-11-10 20:00:00
2017-11-10 20:30:00
2017-11-10 21:00:00
2017-11-10 21:30:00
```

In a database, I have got 249 rows of `program_start_date` so how I can search for the next day format in a database using with `program_start_date` variable?

Comment: Hint: given a `datetime` object, for example `now = datetime.datetime.now()`, you can get the next day by doing `now = now + datetime.timedelta(days=1)`; This will give you this same time but tomorrow

Comment: No you have got it wrong. In my question I am talking about how I can find the next day format when i'm searching for them in the database so I can fetch 10 data for the next day. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: any idea??????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Hey man, it's not obvious where you are searching for the next day. Can you include some sample code to show what you wanted to do? Are you looking for the sql? Can you give an example of what a `nextday` looks like? Like if I say `program_start_date` is `20171108150000`, what should `nextday` be?

Comment: yes i am looking for the sql. I want to search for the nextday in the sql as if the `program_start_date` show `20171108150000`, the nextday should be `20171109150000`, so I want to fetch that data to the 10 next data which it should be `20171109150000`, `20171109154500`, `20171109163000`, `20171109171500`, `20171109180000`, `20171109183000`, `20171109190000`, `20171109193000` and `20171109200000`. I hope that is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt, time

TIME_FORMAT = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'

program_start_date = '20171108150000'
start_time = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(program_start_date, TIME_FORMAT)))

nextday = start_time + dt.timedelta(days=1)
program_nextday_date = nextday.strftime(TIME_FORMAT)

print program_nextday_date
```

#### Output

```
20171109150000
```

Make it a function:

```
def get_next_day(time_string):
    to_datetime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(time_string, TIME_FORMAT)))
    nextday = to_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    return nextday.strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
```

To find all days which are on the next day of a given day, use this:

```
nextday = get_next_day(program_start_date)
nextnextday = get_next_day(nextday)

curr.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE start_date >= ? and stop_date < ?', [nextday, nextnextday])
```

Comment: Thank you, but you have got it wrong. I have got the data when i'm fetching that show `20171108150000` so how i can search for the next day data in the database??

Comment: how I can fetch the data `20171109154500`, `20171109163000`, `20171109171500`, `20171109180000`, `20171109183000`, `20171109190000`, `20171109193000` and `20171109200000` after the `20171108150000`???

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it is working great. I can see the problem are now solved.

Comment: @DannyWhite, no problem